# how to show basic HTML table in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, html, richtextbox

I am using email program to contact with customers. We are defined automatic responses to inform them. We have defined a price list table in HTML format and I want to add this table to email's body text which is RichTextBox control. Basically, How can I add html table to richtextbox? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few components that can be used but VB Express won't let you use them and you'd need to pay for them.

There is something called iTextSharp which is a free set of classes from working with RTF, HTML and PDF. I tried to see if there was anything in it which will do it for you without much fuss but it didn't look like it (but I am a bit tired) however have a look at iTextSharp as the classes in there will help.

There is a RTF Parser for example and a HTML Writer. I mean there are things that will help so worth a look in my opinion.